# How I get dbflib module for python27

Tags: python, error, import, python-2.7

I'm trying to use a script by python to download MODIS imagery. I follow this script: http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/modis.py. 
I installed:

> matplotlib-1.3.1.win32-py2.7.exe
>   basemap-1.0.7.win32-py2.7.exe

But I can not run this script. It has an Error:

> ImportError: No module named dbflib

I try to google search dbflib module. There are two file dbflib.py:
https://code.google.com/p/geoyard/source/browse/trunk/pyshapelib-0.3.1/dbflib.py?r=5
and:
http://liulele84-le.googlecode.com/hg/src/python/_basemap/PLATLIB/dbflib/dbflib.py

But it does not work. Does have anybody know how to fix this problem? Help me, please. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can compile the library against python27 by yourself. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/geoyard/source/browse/trunk/pyshapelib-0.3.1/README) is a description about compilation and installation.

If you are also comfortable with python25 or python26, there are downloadable installer available for python25/26 [here](https://code.google.com/p/geoyard/downloads/list). I've tested the python26 installer and it works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks. I just download only dbflib.py file. So now I need download all file of pyshapelib-0.3.1 to setup, right? Sorry, I'm not completely understand description. :(

Comment: You need to download all files (you may check out the source code via svn).